# How many questions have been marked as a duplicate of "Is there a list of error codes for Minecraft?"

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, minecraft

I have been seeing a lot of questions being marked as a duplicate of [Is there a list of error codes for Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/96496/199843) on the Close Votes Review Queue, and most of the flags are right.

But how many in total have been marked as a duplicate of that question since it was asked? I have seen around 15 just in the last 72 hours or so.

(I don't know if is possible to know at all, but I'm really interested)

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/96496?lq=1 - although I believe this also includes where it was linked in questions, answers or comments too

Comment: You should be able to query that in the data explorer, but I don't have a query set up for that right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Someone already made a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/1167349/duplicates-for-a-given-post?OriginalPostId=96496), and it looks like there are currently 62 active questions duped to the list of error codes questions.  This list doesn't include deleted questions or newly duped questions, though, so the true value might be slightly higher.

Comment: Considering that the questions marked as a dupe usually show no research at all, I feel that there are probably between 80 and 100 in total if we count the deleted ones.

Comment: Weird, [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/254033/rampant-duplicates-questions-with-the-most-duplicates) tells me there are 118 duplicates of it! The other entries in the result are also interesting.